# Searching Database in PHP From single column to all

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, I am new to this but this is what I need. I have a code that will search a specific column and return what I search for, but how do I fix this code to search for anything in my database and display the corresponding row information.

```
<?php
//PHP CODE STARTS HERE

if(isset($_GET['submit'])){

    // Change the fields below as per the requirements
    $db_host="localhost";
    $db_username="megan";
    $db_password="megan";
    $db_name="megan";
    $db_tb_name="user";
    $db_tb_atr_name="location";

    mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_password");
    mysql_select_db("$db_name");

    $query=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['query']);

    $query_for_result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $db_tb_name WHERE 
    $db_tb_atr_name like '%".$query."%'");


    echo "<h2>Search Results</h2><ol>";
    while ($data_fetch=mysql_fetch_array($query_for_result))
    {
        echo "<li>";
        echo substr($data_fetch[$db_tb_atr_name], 0,160);
        echo "</li><hr/>";
    }
    echo "</ol>";

    mysql_close();
}
?>
```

This is what I have. As you can see it currently searches the location column for the information. But I want to be able to search any word, in any column. Currently, it will show the number of occurring that keyword shows up but not the rest of the row information. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: You should not use the mysql_* function set. It is deprecated. You should look into MySQLi and MySQL PDO for better performance, support and security purposes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: SQL doesn't really have a `WHERE *='somevalue'`. You'd have to do a comparison against each column separately using `WHERE field1=... OR field2=... OR field3=... etc...`

Comment: @MarcB you could CONCAT your columns together, and LIKE match off that instead of each column independently.

Comment: True, but either way performance will be abysmal. can't use indexes for matches on derived fields, or `like '%...%'` wildcarding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2d56/1).

The closest you can get is by CONCAT'ing all of your columns, and doing a like, as far as i know.

```
SELECT * FROM Test WHERE CONCAT(cola,colb,colc,cold) LIKE '%keyword%'
```

Comment: :P Works in the demo. What error did you get? How did it not work?

Comment: When I put it in to the code  $query_for_result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $db_tb_name WHERE 
    $db_tb_atr_name like '%".$query."%'");    I changed the $db_tb_name WHERE $dba_tb_name CONCAT (id_user,fname,lname,location) like '%".$query."%'");              it didnt work at all

Comment: You are missing the `WHERE`, do `WHERE CONCAT`

Comment: $query_for_result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $db_tb_name WHERE 
 WHERE CONCAT(id_user,fname,lname,location,email,phone_number,username) LIKE '%keyword%');            didnt work, changed to blank page

Comment: `$query_for_result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $db_tb_name WHERE CONCAT(id_user,fname,lname,location,email,phone_number,username) LIKE '%$query%'");`

Comment: Got it, thanks. I can now search the entire database but it only gives me back the location. If i am searching for all users in a specific location how to I have the entire row come back

Comment: Did you add $db_tb_atr_name to your query?

Comment: yes, $db_tb_atr_name="location", but if I take out the atr and just have name the whole search will not work. I dont want it to return just the location but all the columns

Comment: That is why you have `SELECT *` in your query, this means `ALL COLUMNS`. I answered your new question. See more there.